# Definitively, do you have to invalidate() a CADisplayLink when the controller disappears?

Tags: ios, core-animation, cadisplaylink

Say you have an everyday `CADisplayLink`

```
class Test: UIViewController {

    private var _ca : CADisplayLink?

    @IBAction func frames() {

        _ca?.invalidate()
        _ca = nil

        _ca = CADisplayLink(
            target: self,
            selector: #selector(_step))
        _ca?.add(to: .main, forMode: .commonModes)
    }

    @objc func _step() {

        let s = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        someAnime.seconds = CGFloat(s)
    }
```

Eventually the view controller is dismissed.

Does anyone really definitively know,

do you have to explicitly call `.invalidate()` (and indeed nil _ca) when the view controller is dismissed?

(So perhaps in deinit, or viewWillDisappear, or whatever you prefer.)

The documentation is worthless, and I'm not smart enough to be able to look in to the source.  I've never found anyone who truly, definitively, knows the answer to this question.

Do you have to explicitly invalidate, will it be retained and keep running if the VC goes away?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A run loop keeps strong references to any display links that are added to it. See [`add(to:forMode:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink/1621323-add) documentation:

> The run loop retains the display link. To remove the display link from all run loops, send an `invalidate()` message to the display link.

And a display link keeps strong reference to its `target`. See [`invalidate()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink/1621293-invalidate) documentation:

> Removing the display link from all run loop modes causes it to be released by the run loop. The display link also releases the target.

So, you definitely have to `invalidate()`. And if you're using `self` as the `target` of the display link, you cannot do this in `deinit` (because the `CADisplayLink` keeps a strong reference to its target).

---

A common pattern if doing this within a view controller is to set up the display link in `viewDidAppear` and remove it in `viewDidDisappear`.

For example:

```
private weak var displayLink: CADisplayLink?

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    startDisplayLink()
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    stopDisplayLink()
}

private func startDisplayLink() {
    stopDisplayLink()  // stop previous display link if one happens to be running

    let link = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(handle(displayLink:)))
    link.add(to: .main, forMode: .commonModes)
    displayLink = link
}

private func stopDisplayLink() {
    displayLink?.invalidate()
}

@objc func handle(displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Method definition of [invalidate()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink/1621293-invalidate):

> Removing the display link from all run loop modes causes it to be
>   released by the run loop. The display link also releases the target.

For me this means that displaylink holds the target and run loop holds DispayLink.

Also, according to [this link](https://reformatcode.com/code/swift/correct-handling--cleanup--etc-of-cadisplaylink-in-swift-custom-animation) I found, it looks like its rather important to call invalidate() for cleanup of `CADisplayLink`.

We can actually validate using XCode's wonderful [Memory graph debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH9-DontLinkElementID_1):

I have created a test project where a `DetailViewController` is being pushed on a navigation stack.

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    private var displayLink : CADisplayLink?

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()

        startDisplayLink()
    }

    func startDisplayLink() {
        startTime = CACurrentMediaTime()

        displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, 
                                  selector: #selector(displayLinkDidFire))

        displayLink?.add(to: .main, forMode: .commonModes)
    }
}
```

This initiates `CADispalyLink` when view gets appeared.

[image]

If we check the memory graph, we can see that `DetailViewController` is still in the memory and `CADisplayLink` holds its reference. Also, the `DetailViewController` holds the reference to `CADisplayLink`.

[image]
[image]

If we now call `invalidate()` on `viewDidDisappear()` and check the memory graph again, we can see that the `DetailViewController` has been deallocated successfully.

This to me suggests that invalidate is a very important method in CADisplayLink and should be called to dealloc CADisplayLink to prevent retain cycles and memory leaks.
[image]

Comment: Ah, you're saying this sentence - **"Removing the display link from all run loop modes causes it to be released by the run loop."** implies that: **The run loop DOES hold it strongly.**  That is really interesting.

Comment: If you’re going to remove display link in `viewDidDisappear`, make sure to add it in `viewDidAppear`, not in `viewDidLoad`, to keep them balanced. For example, if you present a subsequent view controller, the current one can disappear (stopping the display link), but you presumably want a display link going when you return back to this current view controller.